# Azure DevOps Rest Api to get all projects with continuation token

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to get a list of all our projects in Azure DevOps with PowerShell using the Azure DevOps Rest Api.

However, when I run the script it keeps returning 100 projects. When I add the continuation token it loops and returns the **SAME** 100 projects 4 times. So giving me in total 400 projects. We currently have 385 projects.

```
$Org = "ORGNAME" 
$personalToken = "MYTOKEN"
###################################################
Write-Host "Initialize authentication context" -ForegroundColor Yellow
$token =[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalToken)"))

$header = @{authorization = "Basic $token"}
$projects = $null

function get_projects {
    do
    {
        $uri="https://dev.azure.com/$Org/_apis/projects?continuationToken=$ContinuationToken&api-version=5.1"
        $ProjSets=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header
        $continuationToken = $ProjSets.Headers.'x-ms-continuationtoken'
        $ProjectSet=$projset.content | ConvertFrom-Json
        $projects+=$ProjectSet.value
    } while ($continuationToken)
    write-host "$continuationToken" -ForegroundColor Cyan
    $projects.name
    $projects.count

}

get_projects
```

Im expecting to see $projects.count equal my total projects that I have in my org which in my case is 385. I can't seem to understand where i'm going wrong and why it's giving me the same 100 projects over and over again with the continuation token.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Still not sure why the **`do while`** loop doesn't work, but I got it working using just a **`while`** loop below.

```
$Org = "ORGNAME" 
$personalToken = "MYTOKEN"
###################################################
Write-Host "Initialize authentication context" -ForegroundColor Yellow
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalToken)"))

$header = @{authorization = "Basic $token"}
$projects = $null

function get_projects {
    $Uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$Org/_apis/projects?continuationToken=$ContinuationToken&api-version=4"
    $ProjSets = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header
    $continuationToken = $ProjSets.Headers.'x-ms-continuationtoken'
    $ProjectSet = $projsets.content | ConvertFrom-Json

    $projects = $ProjectSet.value.name

    while ($ContinuationToken -ne $null)
    {
        $Uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$Org/_apis/projects?continuationToken=$ContinuationToken&api-version=5.1"
        $ProjSets = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header
        $continuationToken = $ProjSets.Headers.'x-ms-continuationtoken'
        $ProjectSet = $ProjSets.content | ConvertFrom-Json
        $projects += $ProjectSet.value.name
        $global:org_project_names = $projects
        write-host "Total number of projects = $($projects.count)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$top` and `continuationToken` for pagination of Azure Git Refs. Here is the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0