# Paginate Azure Devops API

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm interested in finding out if there's a pagination feature available in the Azure DevOps API, specifically for listing repositories of a project using the following endpoint:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

Unfortunately, based on the documentation, it appears that pagination is not supported when listing repositories.

Comment: Hi @ilanAdisa, may i know if there's any update? Let me know if you have any queires. If it's resolved by the reply, suggest to [mark it answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) according to How does accepting an answer work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try below API request to get the paginated output while listing repositories:-

**My API with top parameter :-**

```http
https://dev.azure.com/sid24desai0738/AzureDevops/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=7.1-preview.1&$top=100
```

**My API with top and skip paramater:-**

```http
https://dev.azure.com/orgName/ProjName/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=7.1-preview.1&$top=10&$skip=10
```

**Powershell request:-**

```
$PAT = "xxxxxrp36cuhakncvsamfbukleq"
$OrgName = "orgname"
$ProjectName = "projecetname"
$ApiVersion = "7.0"

$services = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/orgName/ProjName/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=7.1-preview.1&$top=10&$skip=10" -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$PAT")))}

$services.value
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**Reference:-**

[Azure-devops rest api - pagination and rate limit - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63986932/azure-devops-rest-api-pagination-and-rate-limit)

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, based on the documentation, it appears that pagination is not supported when listing repositories.

Yes, it's true.

I used script to create 210 repositories, even with '&top=100' in rest api url, it will still return all repositories.

[image]

For other rest api, you can refer to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64002359/14996050).