# Azure devops rest api is giving me only few releases information.?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have powershell code where I am trying to fetch the releases using azure devops rest api and able to do it successfully I am using below rest Api. Only the issue which I am facing is when I check from azure portal it is having more releases of that particular deployments whereas rest api is giving me only top 6-7 release information?

GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/fabrikam/A13d3daac-03b8-4a23-9cc4-2c3de65dab63/_apis/release/deployments?definitionId=38&api-version=7.1-preview.2

Could someone tell me why this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to fetch? You may get a list of releases here: [Releases - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2&tabs=HTTP).

```
GET 
https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases?definitionId={definitionId}&api-version=7.2-preview.8
```

In your case, you are trying to get deployments. Deployments show each deployment (or redeployment) into each environment of a particular release definition.

Comment: @Shamraj Aleksander Yes basically I am trying to get all the releases happened to that environments. First I am getting all the definitions and then check each releases definitions and if that definition is having that particular environment then get all the release of that environment.

Comment: @unknown which section you are trying to use `pipeline-releases-<release>-deployments` or `pipelines-environments-<environment>-deployments`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are not getting all the releases under a release definition is because the API is paginating the results. You can use **$top** and **continuationToken** to get all the releases of the release definition.

[This is an example for a different requirement for your reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57969982/azure-devops-rest-api-to-get-all-projects-with-continuation-token)