Azure DevOps Api - Release List not returning count more than 100
I am trying get the release details for my project using PowerShell and API but I am not able to get more than 100 results and also getting this error "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ResponseHeadersVariable'
[CmdletBinding()]

param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $AzureDevOpsPAT,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $OrganizationName,
   
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $Project
)

$minCreatedTime = "2024-02-01T00:00:00.00Z"
$maxCreatedTime = "2024-03-31T23:59:59.00Z"
$folder= "\Web"
$count = "1000"

$User=""
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $User,$AzureDevOpsPAT)))
# $header = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

# Get pipelines
$pipelines = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/$OrganizationName/$Project/_apis/release/releases?api-version=7.0&path=$folder&minCreatedTime=$minCreatedTime&maxCreatedTime=$maxCreatedTime&`$top=$count"
# $totalpipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $pipelines -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Headers $header
$url = $pipelines
$results = @();

do
{
    write-host "Calling API"
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = ("Basic $token" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method Get -ContentType application/json -ResponseHeadersVariable headers
    $results += $response.value

    if ($headers["x-ms-continuationtoken"])
    {
        $continuation = $headers["x-ms-continuationtoken"]
        write-host "Token: $continuation"
        $url = $pipelines + "&continuationToken=" + $continuation
    }
} while ($headers["x-ms-continuationtoken"])

$results

Need to get more than 100 results of release ID.


Have you tried the code from this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57982008/3156906 - looks like you have to read a continuation token from the response header and pass that to the url to get the next page of data...

-ResponseHeadersVariable was added in PowerShell 6.0.0. Please run $PSVersionTable on your machine to check the version of your PowerShell. If it's lower than 6.0.0, follow this doc Installing PowerShell on Windows to install the latest version.
The following scripts work fine on my side.
$urlBase="https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{Project name}/_apis/release/releases?api-version=7.1-preview.8&`$top=500"

$url = $urlBase
$results = @();
$token = "{PAT}"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))


do 
{
    write-host "Calling API"
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json -ResponseHeadersVariable headers
    $results += $response.value

    if ($headers["x-ms-continuationtoken"])
    {
        $continuation = $headers["x-ms-continuationtoken"]
        write-host "Token: $continuation"
        $url = $urlBase + "&continuationtoken=" + $continuation
    }
} while ($headers["x-ms-continuationtoken"])

$results | Out-File -FilePath "output.txt"


Now, i am getting different error to the script.
37 |  … $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization =("B …
|                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).

Thanks for your helping, My issue is resolved
